# Showing models only in populated ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm logging the following fields as my output:

```
I/System.out: getLongitude 4.745929
I/System.out: getStreet Laat 199
I/System.out: getLatitude 52.630753
I/System.out: getCity Alkmaar
I/System.out: getZipCode 1811 EG 
I/System.out: getName SUBWAY® Alkmaar
I/System.out: getFacebookID 180894875290925
```

But I want to output into my `ListView` here below you can see a screenshot of how it currently looks like in my `ListView`:

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLxDb.png

Here below you can see what I had tried:

AllStores.java:

```
            Iterator it = subprises.body().iterator();
            List<Store> subprisesList = new ArrayList<>();
            int i = 0;
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                i++;
                Store store = (Store) it.next();
                System.out.println("getLongitude "+store.getLongitude());
                System.out.println("getStreet "+store.getStreet());
                System.out.println("getLatitude "+store.getLatitude());
                System.out.println("getCity "+store.getCity());
                System.out.println("getZipCode "+store.getZipCode());
                System.out.println("getName "+store.getName());
                System.out.println("getFacebookID "+store.getFacebookID());
                System.out.println("next store");
                subprisesList.add(store);
            }
            StoreArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new StoreArrayAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.listview_item_row,
                    subprisesList);
            lv.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
```

---

**EDIT: I have changed my StoreArrayAdapter class**

```
StoreArrayAdapter class which lives inside AllStores.java:
    private class StoreArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Store> {
        public StoreArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Store> stores) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, stores);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
            View storeView = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                // inflate your list view here
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                storeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent, false);
            }
            Store store = getItem(position);
            // use findViewById() to get the TextViews
            TextView name = (TextView)storeView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            // call setText using the values from store
            name.setText(store.getName());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Also this time I want to show you my views and my model called `Store`.

activity_all_stores.xml:

Link to the code: http://pastebin.com/6eiUyPKU

listview_item_row.xml:

Link to the code: http://pastebin.com/CGSVf2Uq

Store.java:

Link to the code: http://pastebin.com/BEsWfaEQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the text in your image is because it's coming from the default `Store.toString()` method.  You can start to see something more interesting by overriding the `toString()` method in your `Store` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getName();  // or define how you want
}
```

But ultimately you will probably need to define a list view layout that has separate `TextView`s for each field. Then you need to override `getView()` in your `StoreArrayAdapter` subclass:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)  {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent, false);
        }
        Store store = getItem(position);
        // use findViewById() to get the TextViews
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        // call setText using the values from store
        name.setText(store.getName());

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I have edited my code. But I still see the same result somehow. Also I have added three files called `activity_all_stores.xml`, `listview_item_row.xml` and `Store.java` in case you want to see them. Could you maybe look at my code again, please :)?

Comment: The only thing I could see wrong is that you are inflating the layout into `storeView` but returning `convertView` which would be null.  That should give you a `NullPointerException`, not the same result as before.  But anyhow, try my updated code.  I renamed `convertView` to `view` because "convertView" is confusing.  It really means "a recycled view or null if there's nothing to recycle". There must be something else not right but I can't see it yet.

Comment: Your code does work, it was my fold. I had another `ArrayAdapter` variable that I was using unconsciously. I had founded this mistake when I was refactoring my code. Anyway thanks for your solution :)!